# Cast struct as another struct in different scope

Tags: c++, casting, scope

Say I have the following code:

```
class ClassA{
    public:

    struct Example{
        int number = 0;
        double number2 = 1.5;
    };

    struct Example ex;

    Example * getStruct(){
        return &ex;
    }

};

extern "C"{

    struct Example{
        int number = 0;
        double number2 = 1.5;
    };

    Example * fetchStruct(void * object){

        ClassA * obj = reinterpret_cast<ClassA*>(object);
        return obj->getStruct();
    }
}
```

Compiler gives the error `cannot convert ‘ClassA::Example*’ to ‘Example*’`
However I need this to make a C interface (which I think can't have Class members as return type, hence the same struct inside extern).

I have tried casting it in various ways, but it doesn't work. This seems trivial, it's exactly the same struct. How can i do this?

Comment: what if you declare struct one time outside of class?

Comment: `return reinterpret_cast<Example *>(obj->getStruct());`?

Comment: It is *not* exactly the same struct. It's two different structs that have the same name and members. Now, C++ *might* let you get away with some arcane incantation of casts, since they're both POD types with the same member types. But *it's a bad idea.* If you want part of your class to be C-compatible, then have that class *store* an instance of the appropriate POD struct. Rule one of `reinterpret_cast` is "never use it if there's any other way"

Comment: Alternatively, it's an `int` and a `double`. That's two, maybe four, machine words. Just copy the data and (if you need to write to it from C) copy it back at the other endpoint. Then you don't have to worry about any awkward dependencies either.

Comment: The real question is why you have two structs, why not just use the same struct in two different places? Then the problem disappears.

Comment: Alright, reinterpret cast seems to work, for better or for worse. To answer john and Bursov, It's a larger library that I'm appending the extern block to, so pulling out the struct out of the class to make it the same for all would break a lot of (albeit minor) things in the library.

Comment: There's no need to copy the struct into the `extern "C" {` block -- just use `extern "C" ClassA::Example *fetchStruct(void *object) {`...  C code that wants to call this will need a C header file with a definition of Example and a declaration of fetchStruct, but that is a separate (C) compilation unit.

Comment: @ChrisDodd So C won't cause problems because of the ClassA::? In the said header file, i just define Example? How will C disregard the ClassA:: part?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to specify `struct` or `class` when declaring a variable.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to modify the C++ header to add this C interface.  Just add the function definition to the library:

```
extern "C" ClassA::Example *fetchStruct(ClassA *object) {
        return object->getStruct();
    }
```

and create a new C-only header file with:

```
struct ClassA;  /* opaque type */
struct Example{
        int number;
        double number2;
};

extern Example *fetchStruct(ClassA *);
```

There's still a question of how the C code gets a `ClassA *` to pass to this function, but one would assume there's another function somewhere (with an extern "C" implementation in the library and an extern declaration in this C header file) that returns a `ClassA *`